# Unable to Uninstall Program : Own by OS

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to uninstall program using `pip uninstall South` and it give me following error

```
Not uninstalling South at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I'm in production machine and unable to fix this issue. What would be the soultion for this.

pip -  1.5.4, 
ununtu - 14.04

Comment: Have you tried it with `sudo  pip uninstall South`

Comment: I'm with root privilege...

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer. :)

Comment: @nKandel depends on how you became root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are present in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, therefore uninstall with `sudo` rights.

```
sudo pip uninstall South
```

Comment: Do you guess any reason why this happens... Initially I was with root privilege and was unable to uninstall it. Though I was able to uninstall other programs with similar privileges... Thanks

Comment: I get the same error even if I use `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by running:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.5.2.egg-info
```

(I found the command on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2964)).

I was facing a similar error on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64:

```
f@f-Aurora-R4:~/ta/hw4/code$ sudo pip uninstall scipy
Not uninstalling scipy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
f@f-Aurora-R4:~/ta/hw4/code$ Not uninstalling scipy at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

Comment: I also had to `sudo pip uninstall six && sudo pip install six`

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution for that is
`sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv`. It will remove virtualenv completely in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by upgrading pip. After

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

and ignoring

```
Found existing installation: pip 1.5.4
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I was able to remove the package I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing flask on Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo pip install flask 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
```

Solved it by issuing this command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade flask.
```

This will fix any issues with flask and install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to

Sudo easy_install -U pip.

It worked for me - 
six: module references **path**
Removing six 1.8.0 from easy-install.pth file
Adding six 1.11.0 to easy-install.pth file

Answer (score -1):

This should fix the problem, as it fixed mine on Ubuntu 14.x.

Install `pip` (even if it is already installed), securely download `get-pip.py` from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Then run the following:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: This seems to just install pip. How is that related to the problem?